# Neo4j Community Edition 3.2 upgrade -where to find config param "dbms.allow_format_migration=true"

Tags: neo4j, upgrade

I downloaded the latest Neo4j 3.2 release (Community Edition). Previously I had a 3.XX version. When starting my DB, I'm prompted to change a configuration setting. Where can I find this configuration parameter for the Community Edition?

```
Failed to start Neo4j with an older data store version. To enable automatic upgrade, please set configuration parameter "dbms.allow_format_migration=true"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When launching the Community Edition, hit the `Options` button and it shows the location of the config file.

Answer (score -1):

here an example of how I solved it:
**( problems opening the ReactomeDB with the new version of NEO4J 3.2.2 )**

here the steps to solve it:

1.-After download and extract the zip ReactomeGraphDB61 at reactome.org/download/current/reactome.graphdb.tgz, I tried to open it with NEO4J 
[TryingOpenReactomeGraphDB61atNEO4J322](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OupKZ.jpg)

2.-Solution: Click in Options and edit the .config file.

3.-Un-comment "dbms.allow_format_migration=true" and save this edited file.
[UncommentDBMS_FORMAT_MIGRATION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgv83.jpg)

Now it is working!